# Issues with making an API call through jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, cors

I am trying to make an API call to the statuspage API (http://doers.statuspage.io/api/v1/).
I am setting the Authorization header like this :

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.statuspage.io/v1/pages/mypageidhere/incidents.json",
        type: "GET",
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.withCredentials = true;
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth authidhere");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("foo", "bar");
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

What I notice is that the header is not being set when I view the request on Fiddler. I feel like the problem is because of cross-origin policy because I am able to see the authentication header I set for any local calls I make.

Could someone please guide me as to what exactly to do in order to successfully make this api call. I have heard of how browsers these days do support CORS, but I would be highly indebted to anyone who can explain to me exactly how I would utilize this support.

Comment: What language runs your API back-end ?

Comment: I am not sure what statuspage uses... would it make a difference?

Comment: What message do you receive on your browser's developer console when running the above code?

Comment: In the API documentation, is there any place that specifically mentions being able to use ajax?

Comment: @DT3 The Dev. Console doesn't complain about anything and there is no message either. Also, the API documentation doesn't talk about being able to use ajax. Their examples are in cURL and they work, so I decided to try and use ajax.

Comment: I updated my answer below to reflect your comments.

Comment: Do you have any feedback on the proposed answer below?

Answer (score 0):

You're likely running into a cross-origin policy error. The *resource you are requesting* must  have an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header that allows you to access it via ajax.

Also, according to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (see "Requests with credentials"), the "credentialled" ajax call will fail unless `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` is present in the headers, which I don't see when I try to make the request in Chrome's developer tools.

**Update After New Information Posted**

Since the documentation doesn't mention ajax, but does mention cURL, I think you have no recourse but to implement this on the back-end. Fortunately, it isn't difficult.

Implement the functionality on your back-end to make the cURL call and have it simply print the response. Then you can still use ajax on the front-end, but rather than calling the external URL, call this new back-end feature.

cURL is readily available in most languages. [Here is an example in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php).